# How to read a file from nested jar at Linux?

Tags: linux, jar, javap

Is there any way to read some files from a jar inside the "outer" jar with `javap` command?

for example, I want to read the `a.class`

```
   A.jar
     |----/lib/
            |---B.jar
            |    |---/classes/
            |            |---a.class
            |            |---b.class
            |            |---c.class
            |---C.jar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JAR files are ZIP files with a different extension. You can first extract the inner JAR, then use `javap` on it:

```
unzip -p A.jar lib/B.jar > /tmp/B.jar
javap -classpath /tmp/B.jar classes.a
```